# When does the code in static/js/app.js in Phoenix get called?

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework

These are some example code from the tutorial in Programming Phoenix book.

In `web/static/js/video.js`:

```
/***
 * Excerpted from "Programming Phoenix",
 * published by The Pragmatic Bookshelf.
 * Copyrights apply to this code. It may not be used to create training material,
 * courses, books, articles, and the like. Contact us if you are in doubt.
 * We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose.
 * Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/phoenix for more book information.
***/
let Video = {

  init(socket, element){ if(!element){ return }
    let playerId = element.getAttribute("data-player-id")
    let videoId  = element.getAttribute("data-id")
    socket.connect()
    Player.init(element.id, playerId, () => {
      this.onReady(videoId, socket)
    })
  }
}
export default Video
```

In `web/static/js/app.js`:

```
import "phoenix_html"
import Video from "./video"

Video.init(socket, document.getElementById("video"))
```

`video.js` defines a `Video` object (Is that how I should call it?), which is imported in `app.js`, then `app.js` runs `Video.init`. If there's no DOM with `#video` the function will just return nothing.

I have two questions as to when that `Video.init` function gets called.

1. Is it automatically called when a page gets loaded? Is there another way to call it when I want to?
2. Is it called every time a page is loaded, regardless of which page I'm in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it automatically called when a page gets loaded?
>
> Is it called every time a page is loaded, regardless of which page I'm in?

The code will be called as soon as the module is included in the page, which, assuming you're using Brunch with Phoenix's default config, will be as soon as the execution reaches the end of `app.js` due to this line in Phoenix's default `brunch-config.js`:

```
  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },
```

So yes, it will be called on every page that includes `js/app.js`, which is all pages in Phoenix's default layout template.

> Is there another way to call it when I want to?

Yes, you can call it from within `web/static/js/app.js` using `Video.init()` (like `web/static/js/app.js` is already doing). You can call it from another module by importing `./video`, again just like `web/static/js/app.js`. You can e.g. attach it to an event being triggered, for example, when an element with id "foo" is clicked:

```
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener(function() {
  Video.init(...)
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into Brunch documentation. It seems that figuring out where to look for answer is often the hardest part. :(